# Why/when is an indirect AC - DC - AC frequency converter superior to a direct AC-AC frequency converter?

Tags: electric-circuits, renewable-energy

I am currently studying wind power and the power electronics used for it. In wind power a generator is driven by wind, thus the resulting power is of widely varying frequency and amplitude. The power grid, in turn, has strict requirements for the input power in terms of frequency, phaseshift and sinusoidal form. For this reason, power converters are today used routinely in wind power.

The predominant way to get the power into the grid is to use an AC-DC converter followed by a DC-DC converter and a DC-AC converter. This seems rather complicated instead of using a single direct AC-AC converter. Why is the indirect conversion via the DC "in-between" route preferable?

Comment: Well, how do you propose an ac-ac conversion otherwise?

Comment: How can an AC-AC converter transform the frequency?
A [transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer) can't do.

Comment: Im not a electrotechnician so i couldnt tell you how it works. However, if you check wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC-to-AC_converter) they list at least 3 types of direct AC-AC converters: Cycloconverters, Hybrid matrix converters, Matrix converters (MC).

Comment: This is an engineering question, not physics. You design both, and whichever design meets your needs better (efficiency, capital cost, operating cost, etc), you pick that one.

Comment: @The Photon: I have migrated the question to electrical engineering with good responses. I propose to either delete the question in physics or link it with electrical engineering. What is more suitable?

Comment: @ckrk, instead of re-posting on the other site, you should have flagged this question and asked the mods to migrate it. Since it's too late to do that, just leave it as is.

Answer (score 4):

The only AC-AC frequency converter I'm familiar with is effectively an [AC motor that drives an AC generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor%E2%80%93generator) via a continuously variable transmission: moving parts, bulky, expensive, short-lived, high-maintenance, and relatively slow response to changes. An AC-DC-AC converter has no moving parts, is more compact, requires much less maintenance. and can respond within a few 60-Hz cycles.